# What's the definition of a "Kafer"

Tags: quran

Assalamualaikum, I would like to  ask you, brothers and sisters, about how can the word "Kafer" be described and defined depending on what Allah (سبحانه و تعالى) says in the Quran.  Because I've already asked this question personally to people that I know and the answers were difficult.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "X" kufr (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/70271/is-x-kufr-reference-question)

Comment: Also see [Are non-Muslims Kafir according to Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48896/)